# member function in javascript 'function'/object is saying it is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, member

I am trying to review some basic Javascript using an online environment where print() is allowed. However, when I try to call say() on an instance of the person, it is saying that "say" is not a function. I have tried this in several different environments with their version of print (be it writeln, console.log, or whatever) and it's always saying it's not a function.

```
//JavaScript-C24.2.0 (SpiderMonkey)

print("Hello, world!")

function person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.say = function () {
        print(this.name);
    }
}

var arrayz = [];

arrayz.push(person("bob",20));
arrayz.push(person("sally",19));
arrayz.push(person("joe",22));

for (var z in arrayz) {
       z.say();
}
```

I'm doing it in just the same manner as this is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS

So I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help me with what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: As you can see in my answer you need to change two things but the one causing the problem is almost certainly `for (var z in arrayz) {
       z.say();
}` instead of `for (var z of arrayz) {
       z.say();
}`

Answer (score 4):

The correct code should be:

```
print("Hello, world!")

function person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.say = function () {
        print(this.name);
    }
}

var arrayz = [];

arrayz.push(new person("bob",20));
arrayz.push(new person("sally",19));
arrayz.push(new person("joe",22));

for (var z of arrayz) {
       z.say();
}
```

Let me explain. The first difference is the `new` keyword. This creates a new instance of the function you've made as an object. The way you did it just called `person` as a function. So it stores the returned value of `person` into the the array instead of the object instance. Since `person` doesn't return a value it stores `undefined` into your array.

More info about the `new` operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Second, you used `var z in arrayz`. When using `in`, `z` becomes the index instead of the object. If you want the `z` to be the value of the array item you should use `var z of arrayz`

More info about `for...in`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

More info about `for...of`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score 0):

### Solution :

Using `new person(...)` instead of `person(...)` will create the object you want, filled with properties you specified by writing `this.xxx = yyy` in the function body.

### Explanation of your error :

You are simply calling the function, meaning that you are trying to get its the return value and push it in the array.

I don't see any return statement in your function `person`, so the result is `undefined`.

You have pushed 3 `undefined` in your array, and you try to execute `say()` on them.